# To what extent is the presentation of the category of X a presentation of the theory of X?

Tags: category-theory, foundations

Various categories have been axiomatized.  To what extend are these axiomatizations acceptable as presentations of the theories of those categories?  For instance, is Lawvere's "An Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets" a presentation of the theory of sets?

Comment: Good question. Bump.